# computer screen randomly turns off

Tags: screen, screensaver, xscreensaver

I installed xscreensaver on my Xubuntu.

Sometimes, my screen blanks for a few seconds while I'm working, generally several times in a row.

I really don't know what the problem is.

Here are a few additional informations :

`lspci` :

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
>   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
>   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
>   00:16.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family IDE-r Controller (rev 04)
>   00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
>   00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
>   00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
>   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
>   00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
>   00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
>   00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a5)
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C206 Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev      05)
>   00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
>   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [Quadro 1000M] (rev a1)
>   01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
>   02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
>   03:00.0 USB controller: Texas Instruments TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller (rev 02)
>   04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller (rev 30)

`sudo lshw -class display`

> *-display
>          description: VGA compatible controller
>          product: GF108GLM [Quadro 1000M]
>          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>          version: a1
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>          configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
>          resources: irq:34 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

Just so you know : I have stopped xscreensaver but I still have this problem somtimes.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: In order to get ideas, other users need to know your hardware specifications, especially graphics and whether or not you installed additional drivers for that, in which case driver version is also required.

Answer (score 0):

Up.

Anyone has an idea ? I had to remove xscreensaver but I would really like either to find a way to fix it or to find an other way to turn my screen off when I'm not here.